# Spark streaming with KAFKA processing time instability from the beginning

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I submit spark streaming job to calculate site pages UV by `mapWithState` func, Complete batches has very instability processing time from beginning.

[image]

Those batches(>45s) took long time at first stage in job. But first stage is only include receive message from kafka brokers(`CreateDirectStream`) and simple `map` for test.

```
stream
  .map(
  x => {
      Tuple2[String,Tuple3[Int,HLL,String]](getMd5(0.0 + ";" + getFormatDate(1600000000l) + ";" +"1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1"),Tuple3(1, hyperLogLog(getMd5("1").getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)), "0.0" + ";" + getFormatDate(1600000000l) + ";" +"1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1"))
  })
```

[image]

I don't known why some batches took 40+ seconds to frist stage. Is kafka receiving instablity? Kafka and Spark In the LAN.

Comment: My gut feeling says: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042295/spark-streaming-mapwithstate-seems-to-rebuild-complete-state-periodically/36065778#36065778

Comment: my question is that tooks >45s batch is not checkpoint. I set checkpoint interval 600seconds,

Comment: If you set it to 600 seconds your RDD linage will grow slower and slower until it stops working. Checkpoint also cuts the graph linage.

Comment: Batch interval 60 seconds and checkpoint interval 600 seconds. It means every 10 batches processed will do `checkpoint()`, liked you say `Checkpoint cuts the graph linage`. But i don't know why batches took 45 seconds? because there is no checkpoint.